# PHP DateTime Inconsistency? What am I missing?

Tags: php, datetime

Using **PHP 5.2.5** I was working with some DateTime objects and noticed a time that seemed off. The problem I'm having may be related to timezones, but I'm not sure - I'm creating a DateTime from a Unix Time Stamp and getting different/unexpected results depending on how I output it.

I created the following to easily illustrate the "issue":

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'); 
$now = time(); 
$now_datetime = new DateTime('@' . $now, $timezone); 
echo phpversion() . "\n\n"; 
echo $now . "\n"; 
echo $now_datetime->format('U') . "\n\n"; 
echo date('g:i:sa', $now) . "\n";
echo $now_datetime->format('g:i:sa') . "\n\n";
```

This outputs the following:

```
5.2.5

1287676530
1287676530

10:55:30am
3:55:30pm
```

I'm currently in the correct timezone, and the server shows the "right" time (10am) when using the `date()` function to output a formatted date, as well as 'America/Chicago' being the default timezone on that machine. But, when outputting values via `DateTime::format()`, the times are very different.

I added the `->format('U')` just to verify that it was holding the correct timestamp.

So, I'm probably **doing something wrong** or I have **the wrong expectations**. So **what am I missing**?

It seems like a timezone issue with DateTime, but if that's the case, why does it show "now" in America/Chicago as ... wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone you 'insert'  into `DateTime` is the timezone of the string, which may not be your current timezone, so PHP can calculate the actual datetime, not the timezone it uses to `format` your output. If you want it to *output* the time in a specific timezone, use `$now_datetime->setTimezone($timezone)`.

Comment: This answer actually led me to the solution, after @Pekka provided clarification. Since PHP discards the timezone information when supplying a timestamp to the constructor, it (obviously?) doesn't remember that timezone for later output. Thus, as you said, I have to explicitly use `setTimezone()` before attempting to get output. This seems a little weird to me, but it works correctly.

Comment: If you need it in your whole application (not just per-TimeDate-object basis), call `date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');`

Answer (score 1):

The [manual on DateTime's constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) has the answer:

> The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

This means that your timestamp is treated as a GMT one, explaining the 7 hours' difference.

Comment: I counted 5 hours, but either way: If the timezone is discarded (which I did miss) how can I tell the DateTime to output that time in my current time? **EDIT**: Upon considering @Wrikken's answer, I realized how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: @anon you're right, it's 5 of course. Hmm... I would feed it with a `date()` output instead: `date("d.m.Y H:i:s");` and add the time zone offset manually: `+0500` (or `-0500`, whatever applies) that way, the internal time in the `Datetime` is correct

Comment: @Wrikken pointed out that the timezone has to be set explicitly. This *sort of* makes sense, as you pointed out that PHP discards any incoming timezone information when providing a timestamp to the DateTime constructor. My problem was that I was assuming the provided timezone information would stick around for later calculation (output via `format()`), etc. Thanks!